# When I left click the image the menu should display in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

This code is working, when the image is right clicked the menu is displayed.

I need the menu to display when I left click.

Xamal:

```
            <Image.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Reset password" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Edit Profile"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="About us"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Image.ContextMenu>
        </Image>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305565/wpf-context-menu-on-left-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the MouseLeftButtonUp event of an Image like this

```
<Image ... MouseDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <Image.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem .../>
            <MenuItem .../>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Image.ContextMenu>
</Image>
```

And then show the ContextMenu in the EventHandler in code behind

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     Image image = sender as Image;
     ContextMenu contextMenu = image.ContextMenu;
     contextMenu.PlacementTarget = image;
     contextMenu.IsOpen = true;         
}
```

Comment: Better handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

Comment: Yeah :) Changed it :)

Comment: Yes perfect . .Thanks