# Open contextmenu on left mouse click wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a rectangle.The `rectangle` has a custom `contextmenu`(just some simple changes made within the `ControlTemplae` of `<ContextMenu.Template>`).What i want is,on left mouse click,the `contextmenu` will popup.

I tried adding `rectangle1.contextmenu.isopen=true` in the rectangle's `MouseDown` event.Yes,it opens the `contextmenu`.However, the `contextmenu` is set to open/pop up above(on top) of the rectangle,i did it by simply adding `ContextMenuService.Placement="top"` to the rectangle's XAML.But if i use `rectangle1.contextmenu.isopen=true` in the rectangle's `MouseDown` event, then the `contextmenu` pops up but in the wrong place,it doesn't stay on top any more, rather it follows the mouse.E.g. If i click the right corner of the rectangle,the `contextmenu` opens/pops up in the right.This behaviour is very strange,i don't know why this is happening.

Anyway,how do i open the `contextmenu` at the top of the rectangle on left mouse click?

**UPDATE**

What's strange is that no matter what code i add to any of the `mouseevent`s,the context menu loses it's placement ! E.g.If i even add `MsgBox("abc")` on mouseDown event, and then right click on the rectangle, the context menu is not on top!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Context menu on left click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305565/wpf-context-menu-on-left-click)

Comment: i've been through that SO post, but with no luck, mine is a rect,please read about my problem(contextmenu not maintaining position)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I can see from MSDN reference [ContextMenu.Placement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placement(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When the ContextMenu is assigned to the FrameworkElement.ContextMenu
>   or FrameworkContentElement.ContextMenu property, **the
>   ContextMenuService changes this value of this property when the
>   ContextMenu opens**. If the user opens the ContextMenu by using the
>   mouse, Placement is set to MousePoint. If the user opens the
>   ContextMenu by using the keyboard, Placement is set to Center. If you
>   want to change the position of the ContextMenu, set the
>   ContextMenuService.Placement property on the FrameworkElement or
>   FrameworkContentElement.

So since you do it not via ContextMenuService you should change Placement and PlacementTarget by yourself.

```
private void Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cm = ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(sender as DependencyObject);
    if (cm==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    cm.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
    cm.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
    cm.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're going for?

```
rect.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = rect;

rect.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
rect.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

// if you want it to be at the top and come down over the rectangle
rect.ContextMenu.VerticalOffset = rect.ContextMenu.ActualHeight;
```

Comment: i added the code to the `MouseDown` event and the reult is more strange.....now it pops up over the rect