# "No target method found" error using cal:Message.Attach in WPF Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I am using Caliburn.Micro. I have tried the solutions I found for this problem but is no good. I have the following XAML code for my design:

```
<Grid x:Name="ActionGrid">
    <MenuItem Header="Action" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" x:Name="miAction" Margin="5" Background="#FF166FC4" Tag="{Binding DataContext}">
         <MenuItem.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                      <Style.Triggers>
                          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                                 <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                              <Storyboard>
                                                   <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                                          <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                                   </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                              </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                 </EventTrigger.Actions>
                          </EventTrigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
                      <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/>
                      <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                    <ContextMenu cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                                           <MenuItem Header="Remove Group" cal:Message.Attach="RemoveClicked()" />
                                    </ContextMenu>
                            </Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
             </Style>
        </MenuItem.Style>
   </MenuItem>
</Grid>

<UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:TransactionViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Everytime I click on the Item, it returns `No Method Found for RemoveClicked`. I don't know what I did wrong. Please help me point it out.

Comment: Can you share your `TransactionViewModel`? I guess, that problem can be in relative source binding `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski my viewmodel is simply a constructor and the method RemoveClicked(). It doesn't really have a connection with the menuitem except for the RemoveClicked method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tag="{Binding DataContext}"` should be `Tag="{Binding}"` and the `cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext` attached property should be set on the `MenuItem`. Then it works if you *right* click on the `MenuItem` to open the `ContextMenu`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Action" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" x:Name="miAction" 
                  Margin="5" Background="#FF166FC4" Tag="{Binding}">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Remove Group"
                                          cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                          cal:Message.Attach="RemoveClicked()" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

Use an `EventTrigger` to open the `ContextMenu` on *left* click doesn't work with bindings and this has nothing to do with `Caliburn.Micro`:

[WPF Context menu on left click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305565/wpf-context-menu-on-left-click)

You may replace the `EventTrigger` with [an attached behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26278554/7252182).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can test this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Remove Group" cal:Message.Attach="RemoveClicked" />
```